# Tricks to make an AWS spot instance "persistent"?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My client uses AWS for his VPSes. One thing he is having a problem with is that if the bids for the spot instance go above his bids, then his instances are terminated. Not such a big deal, it would seem, except that spot instances aren't persistent, so we have to restore from an image every time this happens.

What he is wanting me to do is write something that will check for terminated instances every X amount of time, and restart them automatically. More importantly, he wants some sort of way to feign "persistence". The best idea I have is to simply create an image from each server every Y amount of time and then boot from that image (if/when that instance is terminated).

Any other ideas would be nice to hear. I guess my question is, am I on the right track here, and do you guys know of any solutions for this that may already exist?

**UPDATE:** Almost a year later, I come back here to find all these wonderful responses and much more attention to the topic than I'd ever anticipated. A lot of the below answers, while informative and helpful, question my reasoning. I want to state that, even at that time, I agreed 100% that this was not a wise idea, but was what my client demanded, despite any attempt on my part, to turn things in a better direction.

Thank you all very much for your help. I did end up figuring out how to do exactly what I wanted, and was able to write some code that automatically relaunches terminated instances. It was never easy, but it worked well by the time I moved on to a new client.

Good luck to any of you with the same problem, you're undertaking (possibly by force, as was my case) something that won't be easy. Spot requests are cheaper, as some folks here alluded in their responses, specifically *because* persistence is not offered. Otherwise, I imagine the "spot request" market would be priced much differently.

All the same, it *is* possible, I did it, and it was a great experience. When there isn't a way, you have to forge it! If you don't, someone else will.

**UPDATE II:** I just want to remind everybody that this is something I was essentially tasked with. While many people just dismissed the entire concept at the time, I ended up with an more-or-less functional SaaS allowing one to easily manage and monitor all of ones' spot instances, including the ability to enable/disable auto-persistent relaunch per instance, schedule times for individual instances (that they should or should not ever be started,) etc.

While I absolutely agree that, from a developer's point of view, it is an inelegant demand, and at the time, I did *not* want to do it, I'd still say that it was kind of nice in a way, being demanded to work on it, because not only did I learn a *lot*, not only did I gain a lot of confidence in my ability and my code, but I produced a really useful and, as far as I know, very valuable piece of software for my client (even if they were asking for the wrong things because they didn't know better).

I tried to talk him out of it, but he insisted, and since he was the one paying, I focused my attention there and not only accomplished what many here dismissed as silly but made it *profitable* for someone.

If it were *that* silly, it wouldn't have saved anyone money.

Look, I read this post now and cringe a little. I was a lot more naive, then. I know AWS a *lot* better, now, I code a *lot* better now, etc. Naturally.

But I am still proud of solving this one, especially since it was these fellow, older, and much more experienced, undoubtedly *great* programmers who were the ones telling me it couldn't or shouldn't be done. You were the ones who made it a challenge to me, so thank you!

What if it can be done profitably? Are you sure that it shouldn't?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We ended up finding a solution, and here is what we had to do. I'm going to list this out step-by-step, to make recreating this easier for those who may be looking for a similar type of solution...

1. Create a new spot request instance. Make sure to uncheck "Delete on Termination" for the root device, so that the volume stays behind in the next step. Make sure to note the architecture (we always use x86_64) and the kernel ID that your instance is using (very important!)
2. Now, SSH into your new instance and make a file or something, so you can see the effect of persistence first-hand. After making some changes to the filesystem, go ahead and logout of the SSH connection and terminate the instance.
3. Awesome. Now, go to your EC2 web console and find the new volume that was being used for the instance we just terminated. Right click the volume and select "Create Image". Follow the wizard, making certain to select the same architecture and kernel ID that we noted earlier.
4. Now, start the spot request wizard using your new image. Follow the wizard, again making certain to uncheck "Delete on Termination". Additionally, and this is the easy step to miss, make sure to expand the collapsed section titled 'Advanced Options' and set the correct kernel ID again.

If you follow the above steps to the T, you will have a new instance at the same point that your old instance was at when it was terminated. Therefore, we have achieved some form of persistence.

Comment: Ethan, this method is working fairly well, however it's a long process to go through every time you need to restart the server.  Have you by chance found a way to boot directly from the volume yet without having to copy it to an image?

Comment: @trex005 I'm sorry I haven't been able to get back to you on this. The short answer is, "no". The long answer is that you can work around this issue, too. Get in touch with me, I may have some code lying around that you could use.

Comment: I ended up going a different route.  I have a persistent ebs that I auto mount early in my init and anything that I need to survive goes there.  I then only need to create a snapshot of the root when I do system updates.

Comment: @EthanBarron Hi, i'm trying to do almost the same thing you did. Could you share some of your code? Thanks!

Comment: This is a sound approach and works well. Be aware that the attach might be asynchronous, so test for the device or sleep 5 or so. Watch permissions, and UID's. In a short while and if performance is not an issue we may be able to mount EFS directories.  These can be as small as 1G. AWS doco speaks of imaging snapshots to resize but for linux we can just copy the files to a new, larger disk. Multiple mounts can be used as fast backup destinations too.

Comment: @StiveKnx have I been in touch with you yet? Would you still like a glance at that code? 

It's way too much code to post in a simple and effective manner on SO, and truthfully, if it still works, could be quite valuable (ended up saving that client a *lot* of money). The process was very frustrating, but the end result is essentially an unfinished and basically functional SaaS.

If you were to get into touch with me, personally, I may be willing to share some of that code with you.

Comment: @mckenzm -- I remember encountering this basic issue. The web-based app I built to manage and inspect the auto-relaunching of "persistent" spot instances took me longer than I'd have liked to get to be functional for this very reason.

AWS would have a hiccup or slow down, where it normally would not at all, and if you aren't explicitly checking for that, your code will likely fail.

It was at times a confusing process just figuring everything out. Then, to write the code, was a nightmare.

Turns out to be the kind of nightmare you learn a lot from though, and I'm proud of the code I wrote.

Comment: Hi. AWS has stopped assigning Kernel ID to spot instances. I checked the same after the instance being launched, and it was "-".

Answer (score 13):

**Update: times have changed**

EC2 Spot Instance requests can now be configured to `stop` instead of `terminate` an outbid spot instance or for any other capacity-related event that causes the spot instance to be interrupted.

See [Interruption Behavior](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html) in the EC2 Developer Guide.  Certain classes of instances can also hibernate, with the appropriate agent installed.

Note that this new feature does not guarantee that instances will continue to run, but only that they will restart with their previous EBS volumes, private IP, Elastic IP, and instance ID all intact.

Previously answer follows:

---

Spot *instances* cannot be persistent, but spot *requests* can.

> Persistent Spot Requests: When you specify a Spot bid request as "persistent", you ensure that it is automatically resubmitted after its instance is terminated—by you or by Amazon EC2—until you cancel the bid request. This enables you to automate launching Spot instances any time the Spot price is below your maximum price.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/#4

That keeps the machines running any time the price is within range, but as for the rest of it, consider what your spot instances are doing that has you thinking that persistence of the disks is the way to go.  Think "cloud."  Think "ephemeral."  Spot instances are intended to be ephemeral machines that start up, fetch work, do work, commit work, and if they go away, the work is still out there waiting for the next instance to fetch it again, complete it, and commit it.  You "can" use them with EBS and persist the volume, but if you do, those instances cannot be restarted (as you have noticed).

If your AMI uses the instance store, and stores everything that needs to be persistent externally (in S3, for example) then you don't need to hack around the AWS architecture and you can sit back and watch your machines fire up when the price is right, do their work, and shut down again when the prices go out of range.  And, no bit rot, because every boot is a shiny clean system.

Or, your instance(s) could mount NFS shares exported by a machine that's always on.

Or this: https://serverfault.com/questions/448043/auto-attach-ebs-volume-to-a-new-spot-instance

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for but still very informative and helpful. I will definitely look into what you're talking about, but I'm not so sure it'll be a solution. Thank you for your time and interest, either way!

Comment: @EthanBarron Michael's right, you need to distribute the work and parallelize the workers.  If that doesn't mean anything to you then you're probably better off with a regular instance for the task.

Comment: Indeed we have to design the work units to be restartable.  This may mean persistent (and hence not static) storage, or phoning home to a control point. These are simple things. EFS may help. Typically the major issues are flushing buffers to disk and re-levelling file writes to match rolled back database work if they need to match, The headless FAH client used to be a really good example for a number of years.

Answer (score 12):

(Thanks to Ethan Barron for some of the original ideas. This is a version with some corrections and clarifications.)

[1]. Create a new spot instance. Deactivate "Delete on Termination" for the root device. Make a note of the architecture (x86_64) and the kernel ID.

[2]. SSH into your new instance and create some file, something that should persist beyond the reboot. Do NOT terminate the instance yet.

[3]. Create a snapshot of the instance while the instance is still running (this can cause file system inconsistency on rare occasions so limit writes to the boot volume). Note the name of that snapshot.

[4]. Now exit the SSH connection and terminate the instance.

[5]. Create an AMI from the snapshot created in step 3 (AWS does not support creating AMIS from volumes; it has to be a snapshot. If you are using a leftover volume, there is an additional step: creating that snapshot).

[6]. Request a new spot instance based on the architecture from step 1, the kernel ID from step 1, and the AMI created in step 5.

This should work.

Comment: Was not aware of the importance of creating the snapshot BEFORE terminating. Thanks, NightKnight.

Comment: If the instance is EBS-backed and "Delete on Termination" was unchecked on launch, then the snapshot can be created after termination of the instance without any problem.

Comment: Surely you can poweroff and take the image ? - Your initial image does not have to be from a spot instance, does it.

Comment: @thomie and mckenzm that is correct, I just checked my old code. I think I must've just answered NightKnight without even verifying that what he claimed was true. I probably just figured AWS had changed things to where this approach didn't work anymore. In a sense, it's hacky. You're using spot instances for something they aren't intended for. So, if you can deal with some server being down for a few minutes here and there, but would like it to be persistent, and if this approach still works today, then go for it. You may some a good chunk of money in the process.

Answer (score 9):

I found a handy solution to this problem if you are using ubuntu. It uses a feature called 'overlayroot' that is included in the ubuntu distribution.  The idea is to keep the root filesystem read-only and write all of the changes to an EBS backed overlay filesystem. Because the root is read-only, it can be deleted on termination and all of the changes will be preserved in the overlay filesystem.

1. First create a custom AMI that enables the overlayroot.  Use AWS console to launch your favorite AMI. Log in and add the following line to /etc/overlayroot.local.conf

   `overlayroot=device:dev=/dev/xvdf,timeout=180,recurse=0`

Use AWS to create a custom AMI from your instance "Instances->Actions->Image->Create Image"

Now create and attach an EBS volume to the instance. "Volumes->Actions->Attach Volume" and then initialize the volume.

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf
```

This first instance was only used to create the custom AMI and initialize the volume, so it can be terminated. Do not attach the EBS volume until after you create the custom image so that it is not included in the image.

**The following steps should be followed every time you launch your spot instance.**

1. Launch the custom instance. Be sure to set your spot pricing.
2. After the instance has started, attach the overlay volume to the instance  on /dev/sdf.
3. Reboot your instance. "Instances->Actions->Instance State->Reboot". After login, you should see something like this

   `ubuntu@ip-10-178-74-83:~$ mount 
   overlayroot on / type overlayfs (rw,discard)
   ...
   /dev/xvda1 on /media/root-ro type ext4 (ro,relatime,data=ordered)
   /dev/xvdf on /media/root-rw type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)`

Comment: Super useful! I ended up totally automating the spot resurrection with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The nature of spot instances is they are transient so no you can't make the instance "persistent". However you can make the *data* persistent by using EBS.

You're idea is a good one regarding the images and I'm not sure if there is any other way to do it to be honest.

You can always check out the documentation on [spot instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/) or hop over to the [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa) to see if any of the AWS engineers there have any ideas.

--edit--

Not sure if this would work - because it would incur additional cost, but you could always immediate launch an instance from the image you generate as soon as its generated and terminate the existing instance. It will give the illusion of persistence, especially if you're not relying on an EBS volume for data retention.

Comment: Your answer has gotten me pointed in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps. If you feel this answers your question please accept the answer. Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

AWS has recently launched a new Spot instance dashboard that makes it a whole lot easier to keep your instance in a persistent state. This also included automated pricing and region support, so one doesn't have to fret about bidding the ideal price.
Once the instance is launched, create an AMI of the instance, and that's it.
Next time you request a spot instance, just select that instance from the Saved Instance list. The kernel and the EBS is restored as it is.

Comment: This is the best and simplest answer

Comment: This wouldn't preserve the changes that happened after the AMI creation.

Comment: No, it won't. You need to create the AMI just before deleting your spot instance.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 Spot supports auto restore for EBS device https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/amazon-ec2-spot-instances-stopped-started-similar-to-on-demand-instances/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: In EC2 Console Launch Wizard, this is found under Advanced Details. Click Request Spot Instances. Customize. Select Persistent Request Type and Stop Interruption Behavior.